# postgresql table fails to create

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
create table users (
    id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);
```

```
gokitexample=# \i /Users/henryhudson/OneDrive/Henry/Programming/Go/go-kit/account/users.sql
psql:/Users/henryhudson/OneDrive/Henry/Programming/Go/go-kit/account/users.sql:5: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 5: );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite explicit. There is an additional comma at the end of the last column. It should be like that:

```
create table users (
    id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```